# Run Command prompt commands through flex

Tags: apache-flex, air, command-prompt

Can we run command prompt commands (like copy, rename etc) from an AIR or flex application?
I thought of creating a bat file and running it using fscommand, but that does`nt serve my purpose.

Comment: could you be a little more clear? i'd like to figure this out if I can :)

Comment: Basically i would like to run the same commands that we can run in the windows command prompt. What i need to do is upload some files using the jave-app-engine appcfg.cmd. thus i need to some how run this command from the AIR or Flex application.
this command works from the command prompt--"..\appengine-java-sdk\bin\appcfg.cmd update war"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [Command-line integration in AIR 2.0](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/adc-presents/preview-command-line-integration-in-adobe-air-2), very cool!  But you can only use it with AIR 2.0.

If you want to run it via AIR < 2 or Flex, you could easily use a server-side script like ruby/php/python to execute commands.  Just send the command over HTTP via XML (using HTTPService for example), and handle it in the native language (ruby/python, etc.).  There's all kinds of stuff to do this, but it's complicated to get going with.

If you don't want anything but Flex/AIR, you can only use AIR 2.0.  [AIR 2.0 Beta 2 was released](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/air2/) yesterday :).  Here's a good tutorial on it, [making a native-integrated media player with AIR 2.0 beta](http://mchristoff.com/2009/12/using-the-air-2-0-nativeprocess-api-to-control-mplayer/).

Let me know how that works out.

Comment: Thankyou very much. it really helped me a lot. I was easily able to launch and execute the commands i needed.

Comment: nice, I have to try out AIR 2.0 soon too :)